# Erlang syntax error unclear

Tags: function, variables, if-statement, functional-programming, erlang

I just got started with Erlang. I am trying if statement. I found out one particular behavior which I do not understand.

the following statement does work perfectly.

```
some_comp(Arg1) ->

if 
  (cal(Arg1)>50000)->'reached';
true -> 'invalid'
end.

cal(Arg2)->
%% some calculation.
```

However the following shows an error syntax near if:

```
some_comp(Arg1) ->
Val=cal(Arg1);
if 
  (Val>50000)->'reached';
true -> 'invalid'
end.

cal(Arg2)->
%% some calculation.
```

my question is why does the error occurs. without the if statement the part  **Val=cal(Arg1)** does work well

Comment: What error syntax do you get? That should be an important part of your question.

Comment: @Jubobs I got a **syntax error near if**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because expressions should be separated by `,`, not `;`:

```
Val=cal(Arg1),
if ...
```

`;` is the separator for `if`/`case`/`receive` and function clauses.

Comment: thanks a lot..It worked. I thought **;** was the separator of expressions outside the conditional statements too. **,** was for expressions inside the body of a condition..

Comment: @amerv1';' separates alternatives, like alternative function/if/case/receive clauses while ',' separates expressions in a body. Think english not java.